# Get user group memberships from SID

Tags: powershell, ldap, sid, group-membership

I'm querying AD groups outside our local domain. When searching for the groups in PS I've got all the members that are displayed with their SID and not with their User ID.

What I basically want is to enter the user ID and get all the group memberships the user's SID is linked with.

Below is what I've already tried but with no result...

```
Write-Host "enter user id" 
$user = Read-Host

# Forrest were groups are nested 
$LDAPServer = 'wwg00m.rootdom.net'

# Get SID from user 
$adUsr = Get-ADUser $user -Properties SID | Select-Object SID

# Get all groups from Query in AD 
$Groups = Get-ADObject -server $LDAPServer -LDAPFilter '(&(objectCategory=group)(name=*_EN))' | Select Name

# Get all Members from each group, replacing characters to get equal SID ID like $adUser
$Members = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $Groups -Server $LDAPServer -Properties Members).Members -Replace ("CN=", "") -Replace (",ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=wwg00m,DC=rootdom,DC=net", "") 

foreach ($adUsr in $members) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        GroupName = $Members.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: So by looking at your code seems like you're querying the user on your current domain and then the group on a different domain, question is, does the user has the same samAccountName in both domains or how do you tell who is who? (The user definitely does not have the same SID in both domains as these are universally unique). Or is the user of the current domain a member of the groups on the other domain?

Comment: @Santiage Squarzon they have used the SID ID from the local domain, so when you search for the members of these groups on the remote domain you will see that the groups members are listed with there SIDS of the local domain, the SamAccountName is indeed unique and not the same.

Comment: So the DistinguishedName of these users actually contains the SID (`CN=SIDHere....`) of their other Domain ?

Comment: @Santiage Squarzon, Yes, that's something what I don't understand,  why they didn't use the same user ID as in our local domain.  Instead they used the SID from each user from our local domain

Comment: So when I perform this step as an example, (Get-ADgroup -Identity AVC-P-APPV-HYENA_STANDARD_EN -Server wwg00m.rootdom.net -Properties Members).Members I receive this info:                                                                  
CN=S-1-5-21-132874139-770658141-499016450-112087,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=wwg00m,DC=rootdom,DC=net

Comment: When I do get-aduser S-1-5-21-132874139-770658141-499016450-112087 I got the user ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on conversation in comments this might work. Basically, first we get the `SID` of the user in the Current Domain, then once we get it we can get the user's `DistinguishedName` on the Trusted Domain and finally with this information we can perform an LDAP Query searching for **all Groups this DN is a member**.

```
try {
    # Get user input
    $user = Read-Host "Enter User ID"
    # Forrest were groups are nested 
    $LDAPServer = 'wwg00m.rootdom.net'
    # Get the SID of the user in the Current Domain
    $sid = Get-ADUser $user
    # Get the DistinguishedName of the user in the other Domain
    $dn = (Get-ADUser $sid.SID -Server $LDAPServer).DistinguishedName
    # Search for all groups where this DN is a member
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$dn)" -Server $LDAPServer | ForEach-Object {
        # here we can combine the user's data in the Current and Trusted Domain
        # change the output as needed
        [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName             = $_.Name
            UserName              = $sid.Name
            UserDistinguishedName = $dn
        }
    }
}
catch {
    # Error handling here...
    Write-Error $_
}
```

Comment: it's ok now, When I insert the SID in LDAP filter member  I got what I need, thanks!!

Comment: Will this perform a recursive search? As far as I know, a regular `(member=)` filter only gives you _direct_ membership – you'd need either the "chain" matching rule (1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941) or manually follow memberOf from the user's entry.